# Implementing DCT from its connection to DFT via FFT in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, dct

I've got this assignment to implement a 1D DCT-II myself in Matlab where the 1D DCT-II of an even length sequence is defined as:
[image]

Naturally, using the built-in dct function is prohibited whilethe fft functions are available to me. Using the relation between DCT-II and DFT I've computed the DCT coefficients from the DFT coefficients of the even and symmetric extension of the original sequence as follows:
[image]

However, my own implementation doesn't agree with the build-in dct function. I've seen a couple of questions about implementation of DCT but was unable to find the problem in my own code. My code follows.

```
function X_dct = dct_new (x_sig)
N = length(x_sig);
if mod(N,2) ~= 0
    error('Sequence is of odd length.');
end

x_hat = zeros(N, 1);
for n = 1: (N/2)
    x_hat(n) = x_sig((2*n)-1);
    x_hat(N-n+1) = x_sig(2*n);
end

X_hat_dft = fftshift(fft(x_hat));
X_dct = zeros(1, N);
for k = 1:N
    X_dct(k) = real(alpha(k-1,N)* exp(-1i*pi*(k-1)/(2*N))*(X_hat_dft(k)));
end
end

function a = alpha(k, N)
    if k == 0
        a = sqrt(1/N);
    else
        a = sqrt(2/N);
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no question in this "question"! Please, provide one!

Comment: Why do you think you need `fftshift`?

Comment: No answer to my question? Please try your code without `fftshift`, that might be where you issue is.

Comment: Sorry, I've noticed the notification about your comment only half an hour ago, you are of course correct, it was really unnecessary and even foolish to use fftshift before computing the dct coefficeints as I didn't take the shift into account in the their computation. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Cris Luengo in his comment my mistake was the usage of fftshift before computing the dct coefficients as I didn't take the shift position.